# PHP/Assetic - You have requested a non-existent parameter "assetic.read_from"

Tags: php, symfony, assetic

This is a weird one.  After running a `$ composer update` on my project, I'm suddenly getting

> [Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException]
>     You have requested a non-existent parameter "assetic.read_from".

errors.  Checking the [Symfony 2 docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/assetic.html), `assetic.read_from` is still a valid configuration setting.  My current `config.yml` has:

```
assetic:
    read_from:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../../www/www"
    write_to:       "%assetic.read_from%"
```

Manually deleting the cache doesn't help it.  I can comment out those two lines, which removes the thrown exception, but that doesn't really address the underlying issue.

Were `read_from` and `write_to` stealth removed/deprecated?  Or is something else going on?

---

EDIT: my `composer.json` is:

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.6.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.6.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "jms/security-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "jms/di-extra-bundle": "dev-master",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "2.0.*@dev",
    "roave/security-advisories": "dev-master"
}
```

Comment: What version of Symfony and AsseticBundle do you have right now?

Comment: Can try to comment the last line? Does it give a different result?

Comment: I updated my question with my current composer packages.  @A.L., commenting out the `write_to` line removes the error.  Is it a problem with it not being able to access its own configuration properties?

Comment: @KevinM1 that was my idea. But if you don't define `write_to` is it updated with the content of `read_from`?

Comment: It appears so.  It's correctly dumping the files to the specified directory, and those assets are correctly being displayed in my site.  Really weird.

Comment: I'm wondering if it writes to the directory specified in `read_from` if `write_to` isn't specified

Comment: You can also define the 2 parameters without using `read_from` in `write_to`: `assetic:
    read_from:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../../www/www"
    write_to:       "%kernel.root_dir%/../../www/www"` Maybe it will solve the problem.

Comment: Yeah, using the same path in `write_to:` also works.  It's just weird that the property reference (e.g., `"%assetic.read_from%"`) doesn't work when the docs claim it should.  But, whatever.  It's working again, and the fix isn't ugly, so yay!  Please feel free to turn your comment(s) into an answer so I can upvote and mark it as solved. :)